# Asana Remove User

Tags: asana-api

I always get

Call restricted to workspace admins when using remove user api. Is there any way to work around and remove user from api.

Also when I add someone using addUser api they are added as Guest is there any way to make them member?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to work around having to be an admin to POST to `/workspaces/workspace-id/removeUser`.  This is by design as it could cause security issues if everyone was capable of deleting users in a workspace.

When adding a user with the API, they will be added as a member if the new user's email address matches the domain of the workspace. If it doesn't match, they will be added as a guest.